# How to upload Photo on facebook wall using facebook sdk in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook SDK 3.17.2 for upload photo on facebook wall. I have used number of code to handle this but m not success.
Now i have got a new code which is uploading photo on facebook wall perfectly, but it is working only with my own facebook user id to login. in short it is working only with my Facebook id. When i use any other facebook user id to upload photo its not working :( please help me regarding this issue.
this is my code :

```
Session.openActiveSession(ArchiveLandscape_Screen.this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //                      Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.galaxy_bg);
                Bitmap bi = ArchiveDownLoadImages_Screen.portraitBitmapArchive;
                Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), bi, new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        // showPublishResult("photo_post", response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", 6000).show();
                    }
                });
                Bundle parameters = request.getParameters(); 
                parameters.putString("message","Get a new post delivered everyday\n"+Strcontent.replaceAll("<br/>", "\n"));
                parameters.putString("link","URL");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }
        });
```

Comment: You just swap user id before posting? Without authorisation?

Comment: The user need to grant publish_actions to your app before you can upload a photo. Before you can ask people that don't have a role on the app you need to get that permission approved by Facebook. And remove the hard coded message before you submit because that is not allowed